# iOS direct to scan the CBUUID with service id not work

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy

I try to connect my BLE device,

But when I direct the BLE device CBUUID, it is can't discover,

When I set scanForPeripheralsWithServices:nil , it can discover all peripheral and connectPeripheral success.

Why I direct the scanForPeripheralsWithServices:uuidArray , it is always not enter the below method.

```
 - (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didDiscoverPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral advertisementData:(NSDictionary *)advertisementData RSSI:(NSNumber *)RSSI
```

I direct the CBUUID is below:

```
 - (void) centralManagerDidUpdateState:(CBCentralManager *)central{

if( central.state != CBCentralManagerStatePoweredOn){
    NSLog(@"ble not turn on ");
    return;
}

   NSArray *uuidArray= [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[CBUUID UUIDWithString:@"ABC0"],[CBUUID UUIDWithString:@"27240EA9-D950-4356-A347-DEAAAB8217F6"],nil];

  [self.centralManager scanForPeripheralsWithServices:uuidArray options:@{ CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey : @YES }];

 }

 - (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didDiscoverPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral advertisementData:(NSDictionary *)advertisementData RSSI:(NSNumber *)RSSI {

   NSLog(@"Discovered %@ at %@ of identifier %@", peripheral.name, RSSI,peripheral.identifier);


if (self.connectPeripheral != peripheral) {

    self.connectPeripheral = peripheral;
    [self.centralManager connectPeripheral:peripheral options:nil];
}

 }

 ...
```

I using "light blue" app trace the peripheral info is below, have anyone can tell me what's problem? thank you very much.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You can't scan for device ids (i.e. `27240EA9-D950-4356-A347-DEAAAB8217F6`) - you can only scan for advertised services; your scan for `abc0` should work based on the screen shot you have shown from LightBlue.  Try scanning with `nil` for the service list.

Comment: I had try to scan abc0,it is not work.If I setting the device to default service UUID FFE0 and characteristics FFE1,it can scan.why?

Comment: A 4 digit UUID is a "well known" UUID, but I don't believe that ABC0 is a defined "well known" UUID - https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/gatt/services

Answer (score 1):

In LightBlue show more info about "advertisement data". There you can see service uuid's that are advertised in advertisement package. You have to scan for this uuid's. You cannot scan for other services, because they are unknown before you connect to the peripheral.